# Working with result of pandas.pivot_table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

I am having trouble using reshaped data with pandas. Imagine I have a dataframe in long format like:

```
town    year    type    var1    var2
a       2010    a       100     200
b       2010    a       100     200
c       2010    a       100     200
a       2011    a       100     200
b       2011    a       100     200
c       2011    a       100     200
a       2010    b       100     200
b       2010    b       100     200
c       2010    b       100     200
a       2011    b       100     200
b       2011    b       100     200
c       2011    b       100     200
```

I then reshape it into wide format like so:

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df, index="town", columns=["year", "type"], values=["var1", "var2"]

                var1                var2
    year    2010      2011      2010      2011
    type    a    b    a    b    a    b    a    b
    town    
    a       100  200  100  200  100  200  100  200
    b       100  200  100  200  100  200  100  200
    c       100  200  100  200  100  200  100  200
```

How do I then access the resulting dataframe? For instance if I wanted to get data for all the towns, but only for the year 2010 and type b? I have tried using `df.query` but that results in a buffer type mismatch. I have tried using:

```
df[df["year"] == 2010]
```

But that results in a key error. Any help would be gratefully received. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use [`slicer`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#using-slicers)s:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df = df.loc[:, idx[:, 2010, 'b']]
print (df)
     var1 var2
year 2010 2010
type    b    b
town          
a     100  200
b     100  200
c     100  200
```

Or [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
df = df.xs((2010, 'b'), axis=1, level=[1,2])
print (df)
      var1  var2
town            
a      100   200
b      100   200
c      100   200
```

Solution with filtering by [`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) and chained boolean mask by `&` for bitwise AND, but because filter columns need [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) (first `:` means all rows):

```
m1 = df.columns.get_level_values('year') == 2010
m2 = df.columns.get_level_values('type') == 'b'

df = df.loc[:, m1 & m2]
print (df)
     var1 var2
year 2010 2010
type    b    b
town          
a     100  200
b     100  200
c     100  200
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df1 = df.groupby(['year', 'type']).sum()
df1
```

df can get the table, then just use `groupby`,i think it's easier.
what i get is

```
           var1 var2
year  type      
2010    a   300 600
        b   300 600
2011    a   300 600
        b   300 600
```